# Posting Inputs to PHP inside HTML <table>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm pretty new to HTML, PHP, and javascript. So I'm developing a simple music search website. So basically after entering a keyword, my web will show up a list of possible results, then clicking on a result will redirect me to a music player and start playing the music.

This is my HTML file:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <h1>Search Results</h1>
  <!-- BEGIN SEARCH RESULT -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid search">
      <div class="grid-body">
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody id="mytable">
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I will insert the search results into the table with javascript

```js
<script>
window.onload= function () {
    var results = <?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>;
    
    for (i=1;i<=results.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML += '<tr action="get_music.php" method="post"><td class= "number text-center">' + i +'</td> <td><input type="hidden" name="name" value='+results[i-1][0]+'/></td></tr>' ;
  }
}
</sript>
```

My problem is, whenever I click on a result (or a table row specifically), I won't be redirected to get_music.php and I also can't post my inputs into the get_music.php file.
I know my code is a mess, but please help! Thanks!

Update - Added some pictures just to describe it clearer!
[Photo Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd5z5.png)
So, I've searched a keyword and got more than one results, I wish to pass 3 values ( name, album, artist ) from the result I clicked on to get_music.php

Update - It works! Thanks to Agustin Mita for the help!
So this is my final code

```js
<script>
window.onload= function() {
            getDataPHP();
    }
    function getDataPHP(){
      var results = <?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>;
      renderView(results);
    }

    function renderView(results){
      var data = "";
      for (i=0;i<results.length;i++){
              data += '<tr>';
              data += '<td class="number text-center">' + (i+1) + '</td>';
              data += '<td class="image" align="left"><img src="https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/881765040" alt=""></td>';
              data += '<td class="product"><strong>'+results[i][0]+'</strong><br>'+results[i][1]+'<br>'+results[i][2]+'</td>';
              data += '<td><form method="post" action="get_music.php">';
              data += '<input type="hidden" value="'+results[i][0]+'" name="name" />';
              data += '<input type="hidden" value="'+results[i][1]+'" name="album" />';
              data += '<input type="hidden" value="'+results[i][2]+'" name="author" />';
              data += '<br><input style="float: right;" type="submit" value="Play music" />';
              data += '</form></td>';
              data += '</tr>';
      }
      document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML += data;
}
</script>
```

Comment: table row doesn't have `action` attribute, you need to make your request `get` not `post` and to add `onclick` event for example `onclick="window.location='get_music.php?name=<name>';"` or you need to create a `form` and on `onclick` action use `form.submit` ... anyway putting a json from php `onload` is a totally bad approach

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, so I replaced my table row with <tr onclick="open();">
and added a simple script  named open() that executes window.location = 'get_music.php' ; but I still didnt get redirected to get_music.php,  instead I got redirected to a blank page. Also can you give me a example of how I can pass my variable 'results' to my_music.php when the onclick event happens? thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add form tag before table tag:

```html
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="get_music.php"> 
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody id="mytable">
      </tbody>
   </table>  
</form>
```

On javascript can submit with onclick:

```js
data += '<td onclick="document.getElementById(\'myForm\').submit()" > Any text</td>';
```

Example:
Nota: On php pageyou can retrieve data with [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) function

```js
window.onload= function() {
            getData();
    }
    function getData(){
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(response => response.json()).then((json) => renderView(json));
    }
    function getDataPHP(){
      //var results = <?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>;
      //renderView(results);
    }

    function renderView(results){
      var data = "";
      for (i=0;i<results.length;i++){
              data += '<tr>';
              data += '<td onclick="document.getElementById(\'myForm\').submit()" class= "number text-center">';
              data += results[i].id;
              data += '</td>';
              data += '<td><input type="submit" value="Go '+results[i].id+'" name="'+results[i].id+'" /></td>';
              data += '</tr>';
      }
      document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML += data;
}
```

```css
td {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <h1 id="titleBig">Search Results</h1>
  <!-- BEGIN SEARCH RESULT -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid search">
      <div class="grid-body">
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="get_music.php"> 
                <table class="table table-hover">
                  <tbody id="mytable">
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

#### Update

@KuanyuChwn You need a 3 inputs fields with different name attribute and submit button

```js
data += '<tr>';
data += '<td onclick="document.getElementById(\'myForm\').submit()" class= "number text-center">';
data += results[i].id;
data += '</td>';
data += '<td><input type="text" value="'+results[i].id+'" name="valueA" /></td>';
data += '<td><input type="text" value="'+results[i].title+'" name="valueB" /></td>';
data += '<td><input type="text" value="'+results[i].title+'-valueC'+'" name="valueC" /></td>';
data += '<td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>';
data += '</tr>';
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot! It works like a charm! But I've encountered another problem, lets say I want to pass 3 values into get_music.php, so I have 2 table rows that has same names and authors but different album_name, but when I  click on each table rows, the values captured at get_music.php when redirected there are the same. However when I view the web with developer option, I can see that the input values on the two table rows are different, do you have any idea why this is happening? Thanks alot!

Comment: Or to say it clearer, how do I pass 3 different input values to my PHP file for each unique table rows when I press click on it.

Comment: @KuanyuChwn You need a 3 inputs fields with different name attribute and submit button, show snippet.

Comment: Yes, Ive done that, but my after hitting the send button, it submits values of the last table row(the most recent inputs values instead of the input values of each table rows), so when i hit the send button on each table row, it always submits the same results. I have no idea why this is happening :( Thanks lot!

Comment: update- I fixed it by placing my inputs into a form inside a table data! Thansk alot man, you helped me alot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post it, it must be inside the form tag. You should also add a submit button. If you want the line to go when you click it, you can use the get method with the a tag. If you want to click on the line and perform post, I suggest you look at ajax.

Comment: submit button is not needed